# I need to add first item (select all) row in RadComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, radcombobox

when i use RadComboBoxItem the text doesn't show

```
            <Items>
                 <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="0" Selected="true" Text="Select All" /> 
            </Items>
```

Comment: just shown empty row without text in DropDown

Comment: <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RCB_Industries" runat="server"AutoPostBack="true" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" Filter="Contains" AllowCustomText="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"Text="Select all" MarkFirstMatch="False" BorderColor="#9D9D9D"OffsetY="0"OnSelectedIndexChanged="RCB"><ItemTemplate>
<div style="width: 85px; float: left; padding-left: 15px; color: #37495C; font-size: 12px;">
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nace") %></ItemTemplate>
<Items> <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Value="0" Selected="true" Height="30px" Text="All Industries" /></Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use before Items
`<DefaultItem Text="Select All" Value="0" />`